# Get Response while sending mail through sendgrid using PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, asp.net-web-api, sendgrid

I am sending mail through sendgrid. I am using sendgrid-php library. After sending the mail, i am receiving the mail.

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($username, $password,array("turn_off_ssl_verification" =>   true));
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
 $emailaddress=array('xxx@gmail.com','yyy@gmail.com','hjhjh@radiare.com');
  $email->setTos($emailaddress)->
   setFrom('hjhkjhk@gmail.com')->
   setSubject('Test Mail')->
   setText('Hi i have sent you a mail!')->
   setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');
 $response=$sendgrid->send($email);
 print_r($response);
```

After printing the response, i am getting this output

```
stdClass Object ( [message] => success )
```

even if the mail address is not proper.I am getting the same output.

Comment: Is Success because even if the mail address is not proper the code will try to send it

Comment: ok.. so how to get other responses, like that the mail has been bounced.

Comment: You can't obtain it, this script send, if send return ok! You can however check the mail address before sending (Example)

Comment: we will be sending bulk of emails. so before sending, we cannot manually check whether those address is proper or not.

Comment: if email address are taken from db you can check those email before inserting them inside the db (this won't impact on performance of bulk mail)

Comment: ok will try to do that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The success means that SendGrid successfully received the message from you, and has begun processing it.
To learn the final state of the message, you need to implement the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/), which requires a Bronze or higher package.